# How to populate a Class with Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

In my project I use an XML to import various instances of a class. 
I need to import in a List.
The problem is how to import all "dynamicDrop" in a Dictionary:

XML:

```
<LootProfile name="volpeNormale">
    <dynamicDropNumber>3</dynamicDropNumber>
    <dynamicDrop>70</dynamicDrop>
    <dynamicDrop>40</dynamicDrop>
    <dynamicDrop>10</dynamicDrop>
    <dynamicTypeArmor>33</dynamicTypeArmor>
    <dynamicTypeWeapon>33</dynamicTypeWeapon>
    <dynamicTypeConsumable>34</dynamicTypeConsumable>
    <dynamicRarityCommon>70</dynamicRarityCommon>
    <dynamicRarityUncommon>20</dynamicRarityUncommon>
    <dynamicRarityRare>8</dynamicRarityRare>
    <dynamicRarityEpic>2</dynamicRarityEpic>
    <staticDropNumber>2</staticDropNumber>
    <staticDrop idPattern="100">60</staticDrop>
    <staticDrop idPattern="145">100</staticDrop>
    <faction>All</faction>
    <location>All</location>
</LootProfile>
```

XMLImporter query:

```
var query = from item in xml.Root.Elements("LootProfile")
            select new LootProfile()
            {
                name = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
                dynamicDropNumber = (int)item.Element("dynamicDropNumber"),
                dynamicDrop = (Dictionary<int,string>)item.Element("dynamicDrop) //this one doesnt work!
                //other element....
            }
return query.ToList<LootProfile>();
```

Comment: What is the expected content of the `dynamicDrop` dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary index contain an int from 0 to DynamicDropNumber, content is the DynamicDrop xml Element value. In the given xml dictionary was 0, 70   - 1, 40 - 2, 10

Comment: Yeah, dynamicDrop looks more like a list of ints. Where are the strings supposed to come from? If you just want a list of ints, I think you can do something like this (sorry I can't put newlines to make this more readable): dynamicDrop = item.Elements("dynamicDrop").Select(x => (int)x).ToList() (sorry if this doesn't work, I haven't used XML LINQ in a while)

Comment: my mystake sorry! Dictionary<int, float>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
var query = xml.Elements("LootProfile")
    .Select(item => new LootProfile()
    {
        name = (string) item.Attribute("name"),
        dynamicDropNumber = (int) item.Element("dynamicDropNumber"),
        dynamicDrop =
            item.Elements("dynamicDrop")
                .Select((Item, Index) => new {Item, Index})
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => float.Parse(x.Item.Value))
        //other element....
    });

var result = query.ToList();
```

The trick is to use an [overload of `Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) that gives you two lambda parameters; the item itself, and the index of the item.