# How to populate a Class with Dictionary using LINQ 2

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

related to the problem solved here: [How to populate a Class with Dictionary using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963865/how-to-populate-a-class-with-dictionary-using-linq?noredirect=1)

I have another problem trying to fullfill a `Dictionary<ObjectType, float>` where ObjectType is a custom Enum i've create.

LootProfile.cs

```
public class LootProfile
{

    /*
    dynamicDrop multipli non definiti
    */
    public string name;

    public int dynamicDropNumber; //  = 3 
    public Dictionary<int, float> dynamicDrop;  // 70, 40, 10
    public Dictionary<ObjectType, float> dynamicType;
    public Dictionary<Rarity, float> dynamicDropRarity; // "Common" - 60, "Uncommon" - 26, "Rare" - 12, "Epic" - 2

    public int staticDropNumber; // = 2
    public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, float>> staticDrop;  // 0 - idPattern - prob

    public Faction faction;
    public Location location;
}
```

ImporterXML

```
var query = from item in xml.Root.Elements("LootProfile")
                select new LootProfile()
                {

                    name = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
                    dynamicDropNumber = (int)item.Element("dynamicDropNumber"),
                    dynamicDrop = item.Elements("dynamicDrop")
                        .Select((Item, Index) => new { Item, Index })
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => float.Parse(x.Item.Value)),
                    dynamicType = item.Elements("dynamicTypeArmor")
                        .Select((Item, Index) => new { Item, Index })
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => float.Parse(x.Item.Value))
                }
return query.ToList<LootProfile>();
```

My problem is how to import in the Dictionary the value of the XML Element

```
dynamicTypeArmor

dynamicTypeWeapon

dynamicTypeConsumable
```

in the same Dictionary with

```
ObjectType.Armor for dynamicTypeArmor

ObjectType.Weapon for dynamicTypeWeapon

ObjectType.Consumable for dynamicTypeConsumable
```

Comment: you should probably just create an interface for them IItem and have the object type just inherit from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
var query = xml.Elements("LootProfile")
    .Select(item => new LootProfile()
    {
        //...
        dynamicType =
            item.Elements()
                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("dynamicType"))
                .ToDictionary(
                    x => (ObjectType)Enum.Parse(
                        typeof(ObjectType),
                        x.Name.LocalName.Substring("dynamicType".Length)),
                    x => float.Parse(x.Value))
        //...
    });
```

You use `Where` to select only elements of which name starts with "dynamicType", and then you create a dictionary out of the data.

The key of each dictionary item is the rest of the name of the corresponding element after removing "dynamicType". This will give you "Armor", "Weapon", or "Consumable". `Enum.Parse` is used to convert these strings into an `Enum` of type `ObjectType`.

The value of each dictionary item is the value of the corresponding element parsed as a float.

Comment: Thanks again @Yacoub! You save me again with a very extendible solution!