# How to populate a Class with Dictionary using LINQ 3

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

third appointment with How to populate a Class with Dictionary using LINQ!

related to the problem solved here: [How to populate a Class with Dictionary using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963865/how-to-populate-a-class-with-dictionary-using-linq)

and here: [How to populate a Class with Dictionary using LINQ 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001543/how-to-populate-a-class-with-dictionary-using-linq-2)

I'm suck with LINQ...

I have another problem trying to fullfill a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, float>>` where first `int` are an Index starting from `0` the second `int` are the `idPattern` attribute of Element `staticDrop` and the float are the content of Element `staticDrop`.

See first post for the XML code.

LootProfile.cs

```
public class LootProfile
{

    /*
    dynamicDrop multipli non definiti
    */
    public string name;

    public int dynamicDropNumber; //  = 3 
    public Dictionary<int, float> dynamicDrop;  // 70, 40, 10
    public Dictionary<ObjectType, float> dynamicType;
    public Dictionary<Rarity, float> dynamicDropRarity; // "Common" - 60, "Uncommon" - 26, "Rare" - 12, "Epic" - 2

    public int staticDropNumber; // = 2
    public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, float>> staticDrop;  // 0 - idPattern - prob

    public Faction faction;
    public Location location;
}
```

ImporterXML

```
var query = from item in xml.Root.Elements("LootProfile")
                select new LootProfile()
                {
                    name = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
                    dynamicDropNumber = (int)item.Element("dynamicDropNumber"),
                    dynamicDrop = item.Elements("dynamicDrop")
                        .Select((Item, Index) => new { Item, Index })
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => float.Parse(x.Item.Value)),
                    dynamicType = item.Elements()
                        .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("dynamicType"))
                        .ToDictionary(
                            x => (ObjectType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ObjectType),
                            x.Name.LocalName.Substring("dynamicType".Length)),
                            x => float.Parse(x.Value)),
                    dynamicDropRarity = item.Elements()
                        .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("dynamicRarity"))
                        .ToDictionary(
                            x => (Rarity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Rarity),
                            x.Name.LocalName.Substring("dynamicRarity".Length)),
                            x => float.Parse(x.Value)),
                    staticDropNumber = (int)item.Element("staticDropNumber")
                 };

    return query.ToList<LootProfile>();
```

My current try is the following:

```
   staticDrop = item.Elements("staticDrop")
                        .Select((Item, Index) => new { Item, Index })
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => (item.Attribute("idPattern"). //here miss the second .Select for get idPattern Attribute and use Item.Value!
```

but seems doesnt accept another `.Select` or other so I don't know how to put a nested select.

Comment: Do you need a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, float>>` or a `Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, float>>`?

Comment: By the way, do you have control over the XML? Can you change it? Because if you can, you might model your XML differently and use XML serialization which is a lot easier.

Comment: I need probably a 3 row Dictionary. 
I can modify XML but dont know how to keep it simple.

Comment: Can you explain what you need? Do you want to get the idPattern and the value given the index?

Comment: I need a multi dimensional array with 3 row (index, idPattern, Value).

Comment: And yes i need to get idPattern and his value given the index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate a Class with Dictionary using LINQ 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001543/how-to-populate-a-class-with-dictionary-using-linq-2)

Comment: This is the third pard related to the link you write.
Is not a duplicate.
If you read the second line of the question you will understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the definition of the `staticDrop` like this:

```
public Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, float>> staticDrop;
```

And then you can query the XML like this:

```
var query = xml.Elements("LootProfile")
    .Select(item => new LootProfile()
    {
        //...
        staticDrop = item.Elements("staticDrop")
            .Select((Item, Index) => new { Item, Index })
                    .ToDictionary(
                        x => x.Index,
                        x => new Tuple<int, float>(
                            int.Parse(x.Item.Attribute("idPattern").Value),
                            float.Parse(x.Item.Value))),
        //..
    });
```

The [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx) class allows you to store two or more items with specific types.

I think that if you have control over the XML, you should consider using XML Serialization. You can make your `LootProfile` Xml serialization friendly and then use the `XmlSerializer` class to serialize it to XML or to deserialze it from an XML file.

If you do that, then the Xml serializer will do all the hard work for you.

Comment: Unfortunalty Unity run using .Net 2.0 that doesnt support Tuple.
Mark your answer like right because your solution is ok but doesn't work in this case. Trying to convert Tuple to Dictionary...

Comment: You can use a [`KeyValuePair`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.80).aspx) instead.

Comment: Was a good idea but KeyValuePair doesnt support x.Keys and x.TryGetValue that I need for another part of code.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need this? For each index there should be exactly one `idPattern` and one value.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5gPWAGpb
where ProportionValue is a class for calculate proportion and dictItemProb is the Dictionary that you convert to KeyValuePair

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your requirements. How can a single index have multiple `idPattern` values? On what bases do you group multiple `idPattern` values together? Can you give an XML example that contains more `staticDrop` elements and the expected output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101629/discussion-between-smark91-and-yacoub-massad).